# MongoDB Query additional transformed fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am not sure how to express my question clearly, but let me try to give an example to explain what I want to do.

Btw, I am new to MongoDB and come from SQL.

I need to query a collection and check the specific date field `expiryDate` falls on today, 1 month before, or 3 months before.

I can create a filter to check for those records that expire today by using `{ 'expiryDate':'2023-03-30' }` and this filter returns those records that expire on `2023-03-30`.

However, I have no idea how I can get those records that expire 1 month before (`2023-02-28`) and 3 months before (`2022-12-30`) since the actual `expiryDate` stored in DB is `2023-03-30`).

If I use MySQL, I can create additional fields with `DATE_ADD()` for `expire1Month` and `expire3Months`. I can then filter these new fields if it falls on today (or my specified date like `2023-03-30`).

I know this is possible with MongoDB but I am not sure how to express this in query code.

By the way, `expiryDate` is stored on this format (like string) `2023-03-30` but I can still use `gte, lte, gt, lt, etc`. Also my MongoDB version is 4.4 if not mistaken.

I tried using $dateAdd(aggregate) but it does not work since this needs version 5.0 up.

I also tried $add (aggregate) with date but computing days/months into milliseconds may have issues with days per month (28-31 days).

is there an add functionality that I can easily add months before directly without computing of milliseconds and will work with version 4.4?

**Update**

After some research I was able to create a query that satisfies what I need, but I know this is not the best or efficient query but this works for me.

```
db.getCollection('torjak_requests').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                /* Add your filters here */
            }
        },
        // Add temporary field to convert String date to ISO Date
        {
            $addFields: {
                "expiryDate" : {
                    $dateFromString: {
                         dateString: "$expiryDateS"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        // Add temporary fields for 1 month and 3 months before expiry date in ISO Date format
        {
            $addFields: {
                "expiryDate1MonthBefore" : {
                    $dateFromParts: {
                       year: { $year: "$expiryDate" },
                       month: { $add: [{ $month: "$expiryDate" }, -1] },
                       day: { $dayOfMonth: "$expiryDate" },
                       hour: { $hour: "$expiryDate" },
                       minute: { $minute: "$expiryDate" },
                       second: { $second: "$expiryDate" },
                       millisecond: { $millisecond: "$expiryDate" }
                    }
                },
                "expiryDate3MonthsBefore" : {
                    $dateFromParts: {
                       year: { $year: "$expiryDate" },
                       month: { $add: [{ $month: "$expiryDate" }, -3] },
                       day: { $dayOfMonth: "$expiryDate" },
                       hour: { $hour: "$expiryDate" },
                       minute: { $minute: "$expiryDate" },
                       second: { $second: "$expiryDate" },
                       millisecond: { $millisecond: "$expiryDate" }
                    }  
                }         
            }
        },
        // Add fields for 1 month and 3 months before expiry in String format
        {
            $addFields: {
                "expiryDate1MonthBeforeS" : {
                    $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$expiryDate1MonthBefore" }
                },
                "expiryDate3MonthsBeforeS" : {
                    $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$expiryDate3MonthsBefore" }
                },
            }
        },
        // Remove temporary added fields since I don't need these fields anymore
        {
            $projection: {
                "expiryDate" : 0,
                "expiryDate1MonthBefore" : 0,
                "expiryDate3MonthsBefore" : 0
            }
        }
        
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, and probably best performing, method would be to calculate the dates on the client side.  This would require each calculation to be done once per query instead of once per document.

The query then becomes a simple range comparison of a string.

Define the comparison date strings using your favorite date library:

```
DateNow = YourChosenDateLibrary.todayAsString()
Date1MAgo = YourChoseDateLibrary.dateSubtract(now, "1 month")
Date3MAgo = YourChoseDateLibrary.dateSubtract(now, "3 month")
```

Then the query for expires today:

```
db.getCollection('torjak_requests').find({expiryDate: DateNow})
```

Up to 1 month ago (but not today):

```
db.getCollection('torjak_requests').find({expiryDate:{$gte: Date1MAgo, $lt: DateNow})
```

More than 1 month up to 3 months ago:

```
db.getCollection('torjak_requests').find({expiryDate:{$gte: Date3MAgo, $lt: Date1MAgo})
```

Comment: I initially tried this but since `expiryDate` is in DB which I needed to check if expiry date is equals today, 1 month before, or 3 month before that is why I added fields for 1 month before and 3 months before on each document.